# Filter popular posts by category in a collection in Jekyll using Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a plugin which generates a list of popular posts in a collection in Jekyll based on their page views. Inside collection I have two categories and I would like to filter popular posts by the same category as the original post.

Here is my code I've written:

```
<ul>
  {% if page.path contains '_kb/cat1' %}
    {% assign popular_posts = site.popular_posts | where:"category","cat1" %}
    {% for page in popular_posts | limit:3 %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ page.url }}" title="{{ page.title }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
    {% assign popular_posts = site.popular_posts | where:"category","cat2" %}
    {% for page in popular_posts | limit:3 %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ page.url }}" title="{{ page.title }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```

1. Is there any way to make this code simpler?
2. How can I exclude the original post from this list? For example, if I'm on popular post 1, I would like to show links to popular posts 2, 3 and 4, and not the original posts itself.

I know I can use something like `if post != self` in Ruby, but I don't know, how to do it in Liquid. I've read some tutorials, but didn't find an answer. That's why I'm asking here.

**EDIT**: I tried to access collection's attributes first, as suggested by @matrixanomaly below. But now it iterates through every document in a collection and gives the number of lists of popular posts equal to the number of documents in a collection. Here is my code. Is there any way to limit this loop only to one, the document itself (or the original post)?

```
{% for collection in site.collections %}
  {% capture label %}{{ collection | first }}{% endcapture %}
  {% for doc in site.collections.[label].docs %}
    {% assign category = doc.category %}
    {% if page.category == category %}
      {% assign popular_posts = site.popular_posts | where:"category",category %}
      {% for node in popular_posts | limit:3 %}
        {% unless node.url == page.url %}
          <li>
            <a href="{{ node.url }}" title="{{ node.title }}">{{ node.title }}</a>
          </li>
        {% endunless %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please show some effort on what you have tried (using that code) and what doesn't work. As this question (and the other questions you've just posted on Jekyll) seems to be just 'I copied this code, I don't know how to make it do what I want, pls fix this code or pls give me code that does what I like it to do.

Comment: @matrixanomaly Hi Lee, thanks for your comment. I've deleted the code which I tried, but it didn't work, from the question. You can see it in revisions http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32039416/revisions. This is my own code, I haven't copied it anywhere. I know I can use something like `if post != self` in Ruby, but I don't know, how to do it in Liquid. I've read some tutorials, but didn't find an answer. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: I didn't notice the revisions you've made, thanks for highlighting that, and I apologize for assuming you've taken the code elsewhere (you should mention that you've written it and you're not sure how to continue from there, as your other questions were mostly here's some code). Good to know you've shown effort. I've taken time to look at your question and my answer is below. Hope it works out for you!

Comment: Thank you very much! I just assumed that you should try first and only then ask for help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to get your code to display other popular posts in the same category as the current post. For example if you're on a post about Java, you'd like to display popular posts about Java, except the current post itself.

1. If you've already set category in each of your post, you can use the built-in variable provided in Jekyll, `page.categories` which returns a list of categories, e.g if you have a post under the category of `work` and `code`, you get `['work','code']`.  [Here's a list of page variables](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables).

Rather than `{% if page.path contains '_kb/cat1' %}`, you could immediately get popular posts based on the category. This should work (I do not have a Jekyll install right now to test this).

```
<ul>
<!-- uses categories of the current post -->
<!--I used theCategory to avoid confusion, use any variable you want -->
{% for theCategory in page.categories %} 
    {% assign popular_posts = site.popular_posts | where:"category", theCategory %} 
      {% for page in popular_posts | limit:3 %}
         <li>
         <a href="{{ page.url }}" title="{{ page.title }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
         </li>
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

2. **You can exclude the original post using 2 methods**. Either check if the post you're iterating through has the same value as the current post's `id`, `url`, `title`, something like `{% if popular_page.id != page.id %}` or `page.url` as shown in the page variables. The second method would be to use the `unless` clause.

As shown in [Liquid for Designers](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers):

```
{% if user.name != 'tobi' %}
  Hello non-tobi
{% endif %}
# Same as above
{% unless user.name == 'tobi' %}
  Hello non-tobi
{% endunless %}
```

**I believe your issue is** that you have reused the `page` variable, once you do `{% for page in popular_posts %}` you make `page` a local variable and you lose access to the current posts variable value.

What you would want to **swap out in the innermost loop** would be:

```
{% for popular_post in popular_posts | limit:3 %} <!-- renamed variable -->
    {% unless popular_post.id == page.id %}
             <li>
             <a href="{{ page.url }}" title="{{ page.title }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
             </li>
    {% endunless %}   <!-- you can use if and endif also --->
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**: Since the above code might only show 3, the ugly workaround would be to use `limit:4`, but there is the edge case of showing 4 posts when the current post is not popular, you can then do:

{% assign popular_posts = site.popular_posts | where "id" != page.id %} 
    {% for popular_post in popular_posts | limit:3 %}
        {% unless popular_post.id == page.id %}

{{ page.title }}

{% endunless %}   
    {% endfor %}

I suppose it's a matter of nesting the conditionals as I'm unsure if Liquid allows multiple conditions in their filters, but you want to filter out the current post before doing a `limit:3`.

Comment: Hi Lee, thank you very much for your reply! Unfortunately, I can't use this part `{% for theCategory in page.categories %}`, because posts in Collections don't have such variable. So instead I guess I'll have to use `{% if page.category == 'cat1' %}` for each category in Collection. Thank you very much for clarifications in the second part! I see why I had a problem. But now when I'm on a popular post I have a list of only two other posts. And I would like to show 3 posts, but with the next popular posts instead of the original one. I will post below the code I'm working on now.

Comment: Ah I see what the issue is, since you're using collections, in that case aside from creating a `category` variable for each collection in a separate frontmatter like so: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#accessing-collection-attributes you're probably better off doing what you're doing. 
As for the having only 2 posts, adding a `where` clause would work. (updated answer)

Comment: Thank you very much! I haven't tried the second part yet (with `where` clause). But I tried to access `category` attribute for collections to make the code work for all collections first. But now it iterates through every document in a collection and gives the number of lists of popular posts equal to the number of documents in a collection. (I'll post the code below in an answer.)

Comment: @jupiteror Since you're fairly new to SO, I'd humbly suggest that you upvote others if their answers have been useful/helpful, and then later if they do solve the problem, mark it as an answer. :) Everyone that answers invests time in your issue you may be having, best of luck solving it.

Comment: Hello, I upvoted your answer, thank you very much for the effort. But `where "id" != page.id` doesn't work in the assign tag. It gives an error which says wrong number of arguments, 3 for 1. May be you know how I can do this in a plugin instead? I posted a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029534/how-to-limit-documents-in-a-collection-in-jekyll-by-category-in-a-plugin. I would appreciate if you could give some advice about the logic (first sort, then group by category, etc.). And I will try to code myself.